# Save and Load pictures windows 8 app

Tags: c#, json, xaml

I have some trouble with saving and opening pictures in a windows 8 store app.
Let me explain it:
We are making an Camera app, which is supposed to saves pictures with a title and description (probably in pictures library) and load them back in to show them nicely groups. We are using Json to save the data like Title and description and (which i think is not smart) the path to the file.

However i cant find out how i can load the pictures back in from the path i have.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
```

This is how i load the images in from the path i have, it only works for pictures in the Assets/ folder of my project. Not for the picture library.

```
       private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
    {
        if (this._groups.Count != 0)
            return;

        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json");

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

        foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
        {
            JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
            SampleDataGroup group = new SampleDataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Description"].GetString());

            foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
            {
                JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                group.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Content"].GetString()));
            }
            this.Groups.Add(group);
        }
    }
```

This is how i load my data from the json file. I don't know if this is helpful

I hope it's clear what my problem is? I can provide more information if you need it.

my English isn't very well, so if you have questions, i can provide answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who will find this page, i fixed it by using local folder in windows.
You can access local folder with

```
ms-appdata:///local/dfds.jpg
```